# What's the correct way to notate "a natural number n that's greater than 2"?

Tags: notation

I'm stuck between whether it is

$n \in \mathbb{N} > 2$

or

$n > 2 \in \mathbb{N}$

or if it's even one of these two.

Comment: I usually advocate the use of words, something like "$n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > 2$".

Comment: Agreed. Clear communication is more important than using as few symbols as possible.

Comment: {$n:n>2 , n\in N$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways there are:

- $ n\in \{k\in\mathbb N|k > 2\}$
- $ n\in \mathbb N^{>2}$
- $ n\in \mathbb N$ and $n >2$
- $ 2 < n\in \mathbb N$

In all these cases, using "$>2$" is the same like "$\geqslant3$" by  because that's the same condition in $\mathbb N$.